# How to subset a character vector based on substring matches?

Tags: r

I want to create `ori.same.maf.barcodes` variable to store the strings of `ori.maf.barcode` if the substrings before fourth "-" character matches the strings in `sub.same.barcodes`.

How `sub.same.barcodes` and `ori.maf.barcode` were generated. `sub.maf.barcode` is the subset of the `ori.maf.barcode$Tumor_Sample_Barcode`. The `sub.same.barcodes` is the intersect of `sub.maf.barcode` and `sub.met.barcode`. Now, I want to match `sub.same.barcodes` back to `ori.maf.barcode`.

```
ori.maf.barcode <- maf@clinical.data
sub.maf.barcode <- gsub("^([^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1", ori.maf.barcode$Tumor_Sample_Barcode) # Remove the dashes and keep only the first 4 
sub.same.barcodes <- intersect(sub.maf.barcode, sub.met.barcode)
```

Attempt:

```
ori.same.maf.barcodes <- ori.maf.barcode %in% sub.same.barcodes
```

But my code returns "FALSE" instead of a character vector.

`dput(ori.maf.barcode[1:20])`

```
structure(list(Tumor_Sample_Barcode = c("TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11D-A382-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11D-A382-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11D-A382-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12D-A382-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21D-A382-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A-11D-A382-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9J7-01A-11D-A382-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9J8-01A-11D-A42J-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9JD-01A-11D-A42J-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9JG-01A-11D-A42J-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9JI-01A-11D-A42J-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9JJ-01A-11D-A42J-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9JK-01A-11D-A42J-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9JM-01A-12D-A42J-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9JN-01A-21D-A42J-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9JO-01A-11D-A42J-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A-11D-A42J-10", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9JR-01A-12D-A42J-10", "TCGA-2Z-A9JS-01A-21D-A42J-10", 
"TCGA-3Z-A93Z-01A-11D-A36X-10")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000025e377005d0>)
```

`dput(sub.met.barcode[1:20])`

```
c("TCGA-BQ-7058-01A", "TCGA-DZ-6131-01A", "TCGA-UZ-A9PZ-01A", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A", "TCGA-BQ-5887-11A", "TCGA-G7-7502-01A", "TCGA-B1-A47M-11A", 
"TCGA-SX-A7SO-01A", "TCGA-HE-A5NJ-01A", "TCGA-MH-A856-01A", "TCGA-A4-8312-01A", 
"TCGA-BQ-5892-01A", "TCGA-A4-7732-11A", "TCGA-5P-A9K9-01A", "TCGA-UZ-A9PX-01A", 
"TCGA-BQ-7061-01A", "TCGA-BQ-5876-01A", "TCGA-DZ-6134-01A", "TCGA-BQ-5884-01A", 
"TCGA-BQ-5889-11A")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `sub` to extract the substring till the fourth `-` and then use `%in%` on the logical vector to subset

```
i1 <- trimws(sub("^(([^-]+-){4}).*", "\\1", ori.maf.barcode), 
         whitespace = "-") %in%  
       sub("^(([^-]+-){4}).*", "\\1", sub.same.barcodes)
ori.same.maf.barcodes <- ori.maf.barcode[i1]
```

-output

```
> ori.same.maf.barcodes
[1] "TCGA-BQ-7058-01A-11D-1963-05" 
[2] "TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A-11D-A42K-05" 
[3] "TCGA-BQ-5887-11A-01D-1963-05"
```

#### update

Using the new dput in the OP' post, the 'ori.maf.barcode' is a `data.table` with column named as 'Tumor_Sample_Barcode'.  Extract the column with `$` or `[[` in `base R` or directly use the data.table methods to subset

```
library(data.table)
ori.maf.barcode[trimws(sub("^(([^-]+-){4}).*", "\\1", 
   Tumor_Sample_Barcode), 
          whitespace = "-") %in% sub("^(([^-]+-){4}).*", "\\1", sub.met.barcode)]
           Tumor_Sample_Barcode
                         <char>
1: TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A-11D-A42J-10
```

#### data

```
ori.maf.barcode <- c("TCGA-BQ-7058-01A-11D-1963-05",
  "TCGA-DZ-6131-01A-11D-1963-05", 
"TCGA-UZ-A9PZ-01A-11D-A42K-05", "TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A-11D-A42K-05", 
"TCGA-BQ-5887-11A-01D-1963-05", "TCGA-G7-7502-01A-12D-A43K-06"
)

 sub.same.barcodes <- c("TCGA-BQ-7058-01A", "TCGA-DZ-6131-02A", 
"TCGA-UZ-A9PZ-03A", 
"TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A", "TCGA-BQ-5887-11A", "TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A")
```

Comment: I'm looking for partial matches

Comment: @melolilili i.e. why I extracted the substring

Comment: the code returns an empty dataframe. I also need it in character vector

Comment: @melolilili in the example showed you don't have a match for `"TCGA-G7-7502-01A-12D-A43K-06"` in `sub.same.barcodes`

Comment: @melolilili can you check the update.  it gives me three values in a character vector

Comment: @melolilili I added the `dput` of the data used.

Comment: Your new code returned an empty dataframe. I've added an explanation to my question above to explain where the variables came from.

Comment: @melolilili have you tried testing on the data I showed in the post

Comment: @melolilili In the example I showed, I assumed that you have objects as vectors.  But in your updated code, it seems to be a data.frame object.  In that case you need to use the code with the object name replaced with objectname$yourcolumn (as you showed in the code update)

Comment: I tried your example dput and it works for that example but not for my actual data. I've included some of my actual data to my question in case I gave the wrong examples.

Comment: I tried your example dput and it works for that example but not for my actual data. I've included a portion of my actual data to my question in case I gave the wrong examples.

Comment: @melolilili your actual data may be data.frame.  It is better to provide `dput` so that the correct structure is known to others

Comment: yes, I added the dput.

Comment: works like a charm! Thank you so much! I never heard of trimws

Answer (score 1):

Please note that with the sample data you have provided it is *not* possible for the value `TCGA-G7-7502-01A-12D-A43K-06` to appear in the output.

```r
library(stringr)

sub.same.barcodes <- c("TCGA-BQ-7058-01A", "TCGA-DZ-6131-02A", "TCGA-UZ-A9PZ-03A", 
                       "TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A", "TCGA-BQ-5887-11A", "TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A")

ori.maf.barcode <- c("TCGA-BQ-7058-01A-11D-1963-05", "TCGA-DZ-6131-01A-11D-1963-05",
                     "TCGA-UZ-A9PZ-01A-11D-A42K-05", "TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A-11D-A42K-05",
                     "TCGA-BQ-5887-11A-01D-1963-05", "TCGA-G7-7502-01A-12D-A43K-06")

idx <- which(str_extract_all(ori.maf.barcode, '.{4}-.{2}-.{4}-.{3}') %in% sub.same.barcodes)
ori.same.maf.barcodes <- ori.maf.barcode[ idx ]
print(ori.same.maf.barcodes)
```

Output:

```
[1] "TCGA-BQ-7058-01A-11D-1963-05" "TCGA-2Z-A9JQ-01A-11D-A42K-05" "TCGA-BQ-5887-11A-01D-1963-05"
```

Comment: the code returns an empty dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Your almost there, but your code `ori.maf.barcode %in% sub.same.barcodes` creates the logical equation that returns `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which is what you are seeing. In order to get back the values which equate to `TRUE` you need to pass that expression into a subsetting method to get back what you want.

```
ori.maf.barcode[which(ori.maf.barcode %in% sub.same.barcodes)]
```

If it is a vector this should return another vector with only those entries which are `TRUE` in the logical statement.

And you need to string match to get the entries based on the first part as iod said below:

This is a loop picks them out one at a time and adds them to a new vector

```
new.barcodes<-c()
for (sub in sub.same.barcodes){
  new<- ori.maf.barcode[which(startsWith(ori.maf.barcode, sub))]
  new.barcodes<-c(new.barcodes, new)
}
```

This will iterate through your prefixes and pull out what you want into a new vector

Comment: I think you missed that the "same" barcodes list contains only partial matches, not complete matches, so this will have to use some form of grepping

Comment: this reads in english "from `ori.maf.barcode` return the subset of values in which ori.maf.barcode values are in sub.same.barcodes"

Comment: @iod is right, I need partial matches

Comment: the edits above will get you what you want...without Regex

Comment: It is still returning an empty dataframe. I've added actual examples to my question.

Comment: that is because you showed a list and were passing a dataframe, I wrote and tested code for the list on my own strings, it worked.